# how to replace string with conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

My App have `TextArea` and an `Input`.

`❶=red, ❷=green, ❸=blue`.

**User** writes a `sentence` into `TextArea`: and type the `sentence` into `Input` he want to change its color.

The `sentence` is:

`Hi hola, how are you, are you ok` -> goes to `TextArea`

`how are you` or `are you` or `you` -> goes to `Input`

Now **User** wants to change the `color` of some `words`.

**Step 1**

**User** select `you` and wants to change its `color` to `red`;

**So will be correct with:**

```
Hi hola, how are #❶you#, are #❶you# ok
```

**Step 2**

**User's Idea** has changed, and now wants to select `are you` and change **two words** `are you`'s `color` to `green`;

**So will be correct with:**

```
Hi hola, how #❷are you#, #❷are you# ok
```

**Step 3**

**User's Idea** `again` has changed, and now wants to select `how are you` and change  **three words** `how are you`'s `color` to `blue`;

Here the second `are you` remains from `Step 2`

**So will be correct with:**

```
Hi hola, #❸how are you#, #❷are you# ok
```

**Now lets think** `unlike` above:

**Step 1**

**User** wants to select `how are you` and change  **three words** `how are you`'s `color` to `red`;

**So will be correct with:**

```
Hi hola, #❶how are you#, are you ok
```

**Step 2**

**User's Idea** has changed, and now wants to select `are you` and change  **two words** `are you`'s `color` to `green`;

So here in **Step 1** he had `three word` `(how are you)` as `red`, and in **Step 2** changed the `two word` `(are you)` color to `green`, So `one word` `how` still is red from **step 1**, but `are you` is `green`

**So will be correct with:**

```
Hi hola, #❶how# #❷are you#, #❷are you# ok
```

**Step 3**

**User's Idea** `again` has changed, and now wants to select only `you` and change  **one words** `you`'s `color` to `blue`;

So here in **Step 1** he had `three word` `(how are you)` as `red`, and in **Step 2** he had `one word` -> `how` as `red` and `two word` -> `are you` as `green`, but in this **Step 3** changed only `color` of word `you` to `blue`, so `how` is still `red` from **Step 1**,  `are` is `green` from **Step 2** and `you` is `blue` from **Step 3**

**So will be correct with:**

```
Hi hola, #❶how# #❷are# #❸you#, #❷are# #❸you# ok
```

// My effort is:

```
let globalBalString = "Hi hola, how are you, are you ok";
let reminderObject = {};
```

// this function is inside react `functional component`.

```
const makeStyle = (sentence, colorSymbole) => {

   if(reminderObject[sentence] === undefined){
      reminderObject[sentence] = colorSymbole;
      var newString = globalBalString.replace(new RegExp(sentence, "g"), `#${colorSymbole}${sentence}#`);
      globalBalString = newString;
   }else{
      reminderObject[sentence] = colorSymbole;
      var newString = globalBalString.replace(new RegExp(`#${reminderObject[sentence]}${sentence}#`, "g"), `#${colorSymbole}${sentence}#`);
      globalBalString = newString;
   }

}
```

My solution only work for both **Step 1**, but does not work for both **Step 2 and Step 3**

Comment: Try [this approach](https://tio.run/##lZFRT8MgFIXf@RU3sKR0wTbq47KZmJj47P5Asd4wJgMCzNU0@@2VaWvMfNC9EMg59zsc2Mo3Gdugfbqy7gWHwWACZdyzNPfSrFPQVsES6KOGjTNS5PUAMiC8u72YNuBe6YKQ1tmYIKA3ssWQp3hMQUBEGdpNCcsV9AQgdFmxeIAnVA@d5w2bz/ovTxW90YlTWlZbpy2n7I6WRzZvBBSqKBenaUz7YCGDqzGIh04A38k0ZjRs1n@evg01q5UoikxqMuNISF3DOqGHa/K76XR9fiYJoLkpzYBTTWewMk6dm7I6sW8uY48v@X/@7WX8H9/2Z8YwfAA).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you very much, your solution works only for part one.

Comment: And I have edited the question for better understanding, please check it kindly

Comment: That means you want to reset the coloring before each new search. Else, I do not see how it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't know, how can Solve it, please if you have time kindly edit your code for multiple color and the part two also if possible

Comment: my code in selecting `one by one` and both first step works only as you said in reseting as I mentioned in `Step 2 and 3` does not work.

Comment: I've edited the end of my answer. You have substantially changed the question after answers have been posted. That is not permitted at SO as it renders answers incorrect. Clarifications are fine, substantive changes are not. You need to roll back to your original question. You can always ask another question.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland, The answered is not changed, just I edited for being more clear. may the before edit was not correct, but this time is completely correct that what I want.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you, you were right, I missed something and now again edited as the prev one but clarification is as of now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression

```
(?<!\bare )\byou\b|(?<!\bhow )\bare you\b|\bhow are you\b
```

(with the case indifferent flag set) replacing each match with the with the match enclosed in pound signs.

[Javascript demo](https://regex101.com/r/nsRd7o/6/)

As shown at the link, for the string

```
You should know better but are you crazy or how are you to know?
```

there are three matches: `you`, `are you` and `how are you`. When each is replaced by itself enclosed in pound signs the resulting string is

```
#You# should know better but #are you# crazy or #how are you# to know?
```

The same result obtains if the positions of the strings `you`, `are you` and `how are you` are rearranged in the string.

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<!\bare )      do not match 'are ' preceded in a word
                 break before the following match
\byou\b          match 'you' surrounded by word breaks
|                or
(?<!\bhow )      do not match 'how ' preceded in a word
                 break before the following match
\bare you\b      match 'are you' surrounded by word breaks
|                or
\bhow are you\b  match 'how are you' surrounded by word breaks
```

`(?<!...)` is a *negative lookbehind*.

It is of course necessary to construct the regular expression dynamically. I've constructed this one from the argument `"how are you"`. I don't know Javascript so I must leave it to others to provide the construction code but I've supplied pseudo-code to do that (actually simplified, but working, Ruby code) [here](http://tpcg.io/8mlQ8BoC).

Comment: See *This is a text selection, so it is up to users what they write and what they select, in most cases my solutions works but only for the conditions I mentioned here it does not work.* It means your lookbehinds should be created dynamically.

Comment: @Wiktor, yes, of course, but not knowing Javascript I am leaving it to the OP to construct the regex dynamically. Given the argument `"how are you"` I know how to construct the regex in other languages and assume it is equally simple in Javascript. My contribution is intended to be the regex for the example string, which serves as a pattern for other strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, though not as useful as Javascript, I provided pseudo-code for constructing the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern and closure function to achieve that.

```js
var str = "Hi hola, how are you, are you ok";
const replacer = (str, start) => {
  const re = new RegExp(`(${start})`, "g");
  let s = "";
  return () => {
    s = s === "" ? str.replace(re, "#$1#") : s.replace(/(\w+ )#/g, "#$1");
    return s;
  };
};
const replace = replacer(str, "you");
console.log(replace());
console.log(replace());
console.log(replace());
```

Comment: thank you very much bro, I just pointed an example, it is not always, `Hi hola, how are you, are you ok`

Comment: yes updated answer.. please check. It has to be start from some word. Like you here.

Comment: I edit a `hint`, please kindly once check it, and also consider the `Inverted Expectation` once again thank you very much

Comment: I just upvoted your answer bro still is not solved.

Comment: your example is not comple.. can u add running example.. what is sentence ?

Comment: patern is like this: think a user for the first time select the text `how are you` and then change the color of `how are you`, to `red`, then he again select and change only color of `are you` to `green`, then he again want to select and change the colour of `you` to `orange`, although I am saying an example, so he can select and change any time different text which they works except this conditions I mentioned.

Comment: sentence is coming from `users` `textarea`

Comment: and when he want to change the color of a part of wrote sentences

Comment: Then you are asking wrong question. 3 diff color has to be 3 diff symbol. it cant be hash. use style/class name with span.

Comment: what if user select "you" green and then "are" red, and then "are y" as blue

Comment: yeah it is different symbols for different color, real code is very huge because that I skip it as it is hard to read

Comment: even this is hard to read :-D i think u have to try own. need token tree structure.. i don't think with string u can solve

Comment: there is 5 color possible, the conditions I have mentioned because sometime users ideas gets changed during choosing color for the text.

Comment: Yeah you are right bro, It is more than today I am trying to solve it, but I could find a good solutions, my solutions only works if the user change `one by one` the color of words, but when he selected multiple word to change color for example `first time` he change the color of `I love you`, then his idea gets change and want to change only `love` color, so `I and you` remain for the color of first time, and love gets changed to the current selected color.